# DateTime to String

Tags: c#, date, datetime, visual-studio-2012, filestream

I want to have the datetime in my file, like this:

Date 2014.03.20 11.41.06
or german 20.03.2014 11.41.06

but it does not work. If i try to convert the DateTime to string i get:

1.1.1 0.0.0
What's wrong with this?

```
DateTime DateAndTime = new DateTime();

int day = DateAndTime.Date.Day;
int month = DateAndTime.Date.Month;
int year = DateAndTime.Date.Year;

int second = DateAndTime.Date.Second;
int minute = DateAndTime.Date.Minute;
int hour = DateAndTime.Date.Hour;

string sday = day.ToString();

string path = day + "." + month + "." + year + hour +
              "." + minute + "." + second + " test.txt";

FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(expath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the 2nd line, run it in the debugger and look at the `DateAndTime` variable.

Comment: Why don't you use `ToString` with a custom format string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime` value will be `0001.01.01 00.00.00` when using `new DateTime()`, it's better to use `DateTime.Now` if you want the current date and time:

```
var path = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss") + " test.txt";
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and to all the others too. Is there a possibility to add a [Time ] before the HH, like this:                20.03.2014 [Time ... ] ? If i add them in the String i get numbers.

Comment: Yes, replace the pattern with `yyyy.MM.dd '[Time' HH.mm.ss']'`. Notice the `'` ticks.

Comment: i get this then: 2014-03-20 Ti56e 16.56.22

Comment: Did you use the ticks ([`'`](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/single-quote-apostrophe-ascii-code-39.html))? It works perfectly here.

Comment: yes, but seems like i had something wrong. I've copied your text and now it is working. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

You never set a `DateTime` value, so it defaulted to midnight on January 1st.  If you want to use the *current date* then use `DateTime.Now`:

```
DateTime DateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CultureInfo` to get the correct formatting for various regions. Since you mentioned German:

```
using System.Globalization;

CultureInfo deDE = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
string DateAndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(deDE);
```

It will give you the following output, though:

> 20.03.2014 14:39:12

Answer (score 0):

Example from `http://www.dotnetperls.com/filename-datetime`

Just do

`string.Format("text-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.bin", DateTime.Now);`